# Interact.js Setting dragged on center of td

Tags: javascript, html, css, interact.js

I'm working on creating something of a scheduler, and i'm using interact.js to handle all the drag&drop/snapping of the elements, but I'm having a hard centering and making the elemento to snap to the TD

You can check [this fiddle to see what I got](http://jsfiddle.net/CJLopez/uwwfud3p/embedded/result/dark/), if you drag the draggable to the upper left corner of any cell, you'll see that the snap kinda work, but it won't center the element, nor it will happen always, it has to be on a specific position for the snap to work, and not always will snap it to the inner of the cell, sometime, the drag element will have part of it out of the cell.

I already reviewed the Snap example on the plugin github, it gave me an idea of how to achieve what I'm looking for. A grid system wouldn't work for me as the project requieres a column empty as some kind of void.

Any help will be most appreciated.

The crosses above the cells are where the snap is intended to happen, I mean, it's the position of the anchors, not perfect, I'm still working on centering them

This is the code

```
var element = document.getElementById("schedule");
        var anchors = [];
        document.querySelectorAll(".dropzone").forEach(function (td, i) {
            var boundRect = td.getBoundingClientRect();
            var anchor = {
                x: boundRect.left + 30,
                y: boundRect.top + 15,
                range: 20
            }
            anchors.push(anchor);
        });
        anchors.forEach(function(anchor, i){
            var textNode = document.createElement("div");
            textNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("+"));
            textNode.style.position = "absolute";
            textNode.style.top = anchor.y + "px";
            textNode.style.left = anchor.x  + "px";
            textNode.style.zIndex = 100;
            textNode.style.fontWeight = "bolder";
            document.querySelector("#wrapper").appendChild(textNode);
        });

        // target elements with the "draggable" class
        interact('.draggable')
            .draggable({
                // enable inertial throwing
                inertia: true,
                // snapping to grid
                snap: {
                    targets: anchors,
                    enabled: true,
                    endOnly: true,
                    //offset: 'startCoords'
                },
                // keep the element within the area of it's parent
                restrict: {
                    drag: element,
                    endOnly: false,
                    elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
                },
                // enable autoScroll
                autoScroll: true,
                // call this function on every dragmove event
                onmove: dragMoveListener,
                // call this function on every dragend event
                onend: function (event) {
                }
            });

        // enable draggables to be dropped into this
            interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
                // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
                accept: '#dragabble',
                // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
                overlap: 0.6,

                // listen for drop related events:

                ondropactivate: function (event) {
                    // add active dropzone feedback
                    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');                    
                },
                ondragenter: function (event) {
                    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
                    dropzoneElement = event.target;

                    // feedback the possibility of a drop
                    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
                    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
                    draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
                    var dropRect = interact.getElementRect(event.target),
                    dropCenter = {
                        x: dropRect.left + 30,
                        y: dropRect.top  + 15
                    };

                    event.draggable.snap({
                      anchors: dropCenter
                    });
                },
                ondragleave: function (event) {
                    // remove the drop feedback style
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
                    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
                    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
                    event.draggable.snap(false);                    
                },
                ondrop: function (event) {
                    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
                },
                ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
                    // remove active dropzone feedback
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
                }
            });

        function dragMoveListener(event) {
            var target = event.target,
            // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

            // translate the element
            target.style.webkitTransform =
            target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

            // update the posiion attributes
            target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
            target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        }

        // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
        window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, never mind, I decided to implement my own snapping the way I want it/need it.

I just added a little code to the `ondrop` event, to set the `dragabble` to the center of the td where it landed and that made the snap I need

```js
var element = document.getElementById("schedule");

        // target elements with the "draggable" class
        interact('.draggable')
            .draggable({
                // enable inertial throwing
                inertia: true,
                // keep the element within the area of it's parent
                restrict: {
                    drag: element,
                    endOnly: true,
                    elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
                },
                // enable autoScroll
                autoScroll: true,
                // call this function on every dragmove event
                onmove: dragMoveListener,
                // call this function on every dragend event
                onend: function (event) {
                }
            });

        // enable draggables to be dropped into this
            interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
                // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
                accept: '#dragabble',
                // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
                overlap: 0.6,

                // listen for drop related events:

                ondropactivate: function (event) {
                    // add active dropzone feedback
                    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');                    
                },
                ondragenter: function (event) {
                    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
                    dropzoneElement = event.target;

                    // feedback the possibility of a drop
                    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
                    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
                    draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
                },
                ondragleave: function (event) {
                    // remove the drop feedback style
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
                    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
                    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
                },
                ondrop: function (event) {
                    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
                        dropzoneElement = event.target,
                        dropRect = getOffset(dropzoneElement),
                        x = dropRect.left,
                        y = dropRect.top;
                    draggableElement.textContent = 'Dropped';
                    // translate the element
                    draggableElement.style.webkitTransform =
                    draggableElement.style.transform =
                        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

                    // update the posiion attributes
                    draggableElement.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                    draggableElement.setAttribute('data-y', y);                
                    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
                },
                ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
                    // remove active dropzone feedback
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
                    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
                }
            });

        function dragMoveListener(event) {
            var target = event.target,
            // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
            x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
            y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

            // translate the element
            target.style.webkitTransform =
            target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

            // update the posiion attributes
            target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
            target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
        }

        function getOffset(el) {
          el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            left: el.left + window.scrollX,
            top: el.top + window.scrollY
          }
        }
        // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
        window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```

```css
       td
        {
            width: 68px;
            height: 32px;
        }
        
        #wrapper 
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #dropZone {
          height: 140px;
            background-color: Gray;
        }
        
        .dropzone {
          background-color: #ccc;
          border: dashed 4px transparent;
          border-radius: 4px;
          /*margin: 10px auto 30px;*/
          padding: 6px;
          /*width: 80%;*/
          transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }
        
        .drop-active {
          border-color: #aaa;
        }

        .drop-target {
          background-color: #29e;
          border-color: #fff;
          border-style: solid;
        }

        .drag-drop {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 60px;
          height: 30px;
          /*padding: 2em 0.5em;*/

          color: #fff;
          background-color: #29e;
          border: solid 2px #fff;

          -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
                  transform: translate(0px, 0px);

          transition: background-color 0.3s;
        }

        .drag-drop.can-drop {
          color: #000;
          background-color: #4e4;
        }

        #draggable::before {
          content: "#" attr(id);
          font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js"></script>
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="dragabble" class="draggable drag-drop">
            #yes-drop
        </div>

        <!--<div id="dropZone" class="dropzone"></div>-->
        <table id="schedule" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Ven1</th>
                    <th>Ven2</th>
                    <th>Ven3</th>
                    <th>Ven4</th>
                    <th>Ven5</th>
                    <th>N.Crane</th>
                    <th>S.Crane</th>
                    <th>TrainWell 1</th>
                    <th>TrainWell 2</th>
                    <th>InbShip</th>
                    <th>InbCoat</th>
                    <th>InbTrain</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>0/0[2]</td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0/6[3]</td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0/6[2]</td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0/6[4]</td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                    <td class="dropzone"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Any way, if someone has a suggestion or knows how to make it work using the snap functionality of interact.js, it will be most appreciated, be it with snapgrid or anchors